# Format footnotes

Tags: citing, footnotes

How can I adjust the indent of the footnote (red arrow) and the space after the number in the footnote (blue arrow)? And why do I get this ugly new line artifact after a normal line break (green arrow)?

[image]

Thanks!

Comment: Which document class are you using? If KOMA-Script, you can use `\deffootnote` …

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You didn't tell us which document class you use.  So I will add here two possibilities: one for KOMA-Script, one for class article.

I put both together in the following MWE, please just change the document class and move the comment signs.

1. KOMA-Script: In the documentation `scrguide.pdf`, page 92 (German, you seems to be a German) you will find `\deffootnote[Markenbreite]{Einzug}{Absatzeinzug}{Markendefinition}`.  To get a footnote as required by the german Duden (rules for wrighting) please use:

   `\deffootnote{1.5em}{1em}{% [labelwidth]{labelindent}{paragraph indent}{label definition`

   `\makebox[1.5em][l]{\thefootnotemark}}%`
2. With class `article` you need t define an own list for the footnote.  Please see the following code.

With both solutions you get the same result as shown later in the screenshot.

Code for class `article`:

```
\renewcommand{\@makefntext}[1]{%
 \setlength{\parindent}{0pt}%
 \begin{list}{}{\setlength{\labelwidth}{1.5em}%
 \setlength{\leftmargin}{\labelwidth}%
 \setlength{\labelsep}{3pt}%
 \setlength{\itemsep}{0pt}%
 \setlength{\parsep}{0pt}%
 \setlength{\topsep}{0pt}%
% \setlength{\rightmargin}{0.2\textwidth}%
 \footnotesize}%
 \item[\@makefnmark\hfil]#1%
 \end{list}%
}
```

Complete MWE:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl} % article

\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{showframe} %=====================================

% With Koma-Script: 
\deffootnote{1.5em}{1em}{% [labelwidth]{labelindent}{paragraph indent}{label definition
  \makebox[1.5em][l]{\thefootnotemark}%
}

%Without Koma-Script, for example article:
%\makeatletter % needed for @
%\renewcommand{\@makefntext}[1]{%
 %\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}%
 %\begin{list}{}{\setlength{\labelwidth}{1.5em}%
 %\setlength{\leftmargin}{\labelwidth}%
 %\setlength{\labelsep}{3pt}%
 %\setlength{\itemsep}{0pt}%
 %\setlength{\parsep}{0pt}%
 %\setlength{\topsep}{0pt}%
%% \setlength{\rightmargin}{0.2\textwidth}%
 %\footnotesize}%
 %\item[\@makefnmark\hfil]#1%
 %\end{list}%
%}
%\makeatother % ends \makeatletter


\begin{document}

text\footnote{Footnote 1} text\footnote{\blindtext}

\end{document}
```

and the result:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Here’s an example for the usage of `\deffootnotemark`. While version A is maybe more like what you want, I’d prefer version B since there’s no reason to make the numbers as subscript. They are more visible as normal figures …

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

% \deffootnote[mark width]{indent}{parindent}{definition of mark}

% A
\deffootnote[1em]{1em}{1em}{%
   \textsuperscript{\thefootnotemark}%
}

% B
%\deffootnote[1.5em]{1.5em}{1em}{%
%   \makebox[1.5em][l]{\thefootnotemark}%
%}

\begin{document}
Test\footnote{Some footnote text.}
Test\footnote{Some long long long footnote text. Some long long long footnote text.
   Some long long long footnote text. Some long long long footnote text}
Test\footnote{Some footnote text.

With a paragraph. Some more text.}
\end{document}
```

With a **non KOMA-Script** class the package `scrextend` gives you the possibility to use `\deffonotnote` too (thanks @esdd for point out):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{scrextend}

\deffootnote[1em]{1em}{1em}{%
   \textsuperscript{\thefootnotemark}%
}

\begin{document}
Test\footnote{Some footnote text.}
\end{document}
```

Comment: This works also with `\documentclass{article}\usepackage{scrextend}`.

Comment: @esdd: Thanks! I added this to my answer :-)