# Space between footnotes and text

Tags: footnotes, koma-script, setspace

I am using koma-script for writing my final thesis and have the following problem: The space between my main text body and the footnoterule is not unified, it differs at every page and it is mainly too huge. My university wants it to be 1cm, but I have no idea how to do that. Can anyone help?
This is my preamble:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{scrreprt}

\usepackage{ucs}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc} % Eingabekodierung: UTF-8
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} % ordentliche Trennung
\usepackage[french,USenglish,UKenglish,ngerman]{babel}
% \usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{lmodern} % ordentliche Schriften
\usepackage{relsize}
\usepackage[babel,style=swiss,maxlevel=3,threshold=3]{csquotes}
    \newenvironment*{smallquote} %Alle \blockquotes sind mit einfachem Zeilenabstand und in kleinerer (\footnotesize) Größe.
    {\quote\singlespacing\smaller}
    {\endquote}
    \SetBlockEnvironment{smallquote}


\usepackage{extsizes}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage[top=2.5cm,bottom=3.5cm,left=2.5cm,right=4cm,headheight=14.5pt]{geometry}
%\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{lettrine}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage{poetrytex}


\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{epigraph}
    \setlength\epigraphwidth{0.75\textwidth}
    \setlength\epigraphrule{0pt}
    \renewcommand{\epigraphsize}{\footnotesize}
    \renewcommand{\beforeepigraphskip}{12pt}
    \renewcommand{\afterepigraphskip}{12pt}
\usepackage[]{acronym}


% An alternative to fancyhdr
\usepackage[markcase=ignoreupper]{scrlayer-scrpage}
\clearpairofpagestyles
\automark[section]{section}
\ohead{\headmark}
\ofoot*{\pagemark}



\usepackage{titlesec}
\titlespacing{\chapter}{0pt}{24pt}{12pt} % damit wird der Abstand vor und nach Kapiteln und (Sub-)Sections geregelt
\titlespacing{\section}{0pt}{24pt}{12pt}
\titlespacing{\subsection}{0pt}{24pt}{12pt}
\titlespacing{\invisiblesection}{0pt}{24pt}{12pt}

\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
{\normalfont\Large\bfseries}
{\chaptertitlename\thechapter}{14pt}{\Large}

\titleformat{\section}[display]
{\normalfont\large\bfseries}
{\thesection}{14pt}{\large}

\newcommand\invisiblesection[1]{%
    \refstepcounter{section}%
    \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\protect\numberline{\thesection}#1}%
    \sectionmark{#1}}

\newcommand{\nocontentsline}[3]{}
\newcommand{\tocless}[2]{\bgroup\let\addcontentsline=\nocontentsline#1{#2}\egroup}

\usepackage{tocloft} %für Schriftgröße etc. des Inhaltsverzeichnis und des Abbildungsverzeichnis
    \renewcommand\cftchapfont{\large}
    \renewcommand\cftsecfont{\large}
    \renewcommand{\cfttoctitlefont}{\large\bfseries}
    \renewcommand{\cftloftitlefont}{\normalfont\large\bfseries}
    \renewcommand\cftbeforetoctitleskip{24pt}
    \renewcommand\cftaftertoctitleskip{12pt}
    \renewcommand\cftbeforeloftitleskip{24pt}
    \renewcommand\cftafterloftitleskip{12pt}




\usepackage{hyperref}
\makeatletter %sorgt dafür, dass die Fußnoten am linken Rand nicht überstehen, sondern mit dem Horizontalstrich gemeinsam schließen.
\renewcommand{\@makefntext}[1]{
    \parindent 1em%
    \noindent\normalfont\@thefnmark~#1
}
\makeatother

% \textheight=\vfill% just for the example, wofür?
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\pagenumbering{arabic}
\deffootnote[1em]{1.5em}{1em}{\thefootnotemark\ }

\makeatletter
\@ifdefinable{\org@makefntext}{%
    \let\org@makefntext\@makefntext
    \renewcommand*{\@makefntext}{%
        \addtolength{\hsize}{-1cm}%
        \org@makefntext
    }%
}
\makeatother
\setlength{\skip\footins}{1em}
```

Comment: Maybe issuing `\flushbottom` before `\begin{document}`?

Comment: BTW: KOMA-Script has an own command for defining footnotes. Please see http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/310103/format-footnotes/310133#310133

Answer (score 3):

The `scrreprt` class when used with the `oneside` default option, just like `report`, uses a `\raggedbottom` setting, so pages are not “filled up to the bottom”.

Declare `\flushbottom` in the preamble.

Note that Koma-script classes have their own method for changing the format of footnotes, see answers to [Format footnotes](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/310103/format-footnotes/310133#310133)